# Use Tesseract ocr in Android studio but the program exits unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract in Android Studio to recognize texts in a picture. When I call the following function like this:

```
String textResult = doOcr(bitmapTreated,"eng");
```

Then the program exits.

```
public String doOcr(Bitmap bitmap, String language) {
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.init(getSDPath(), language);
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
        String text = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.clear();
        baseApi.end();
        return text;
    }
```

Here are the results:

```
06-24 21:37:23.205 30643-30643/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-24 21:37:23.335 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getTotalMemory ()J
06-24 21:37:23.335 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getFreeMemory ()J
06-24 21:37:23.365 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
06-24 21:37:23.365 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 422: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
06-24 21:37:23.365 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-24 21:37:23.365 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
06-24 21:37:23.365 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 444: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
06-24 21:37:23.365 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-24 21:37:23.435 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.1_RB1.04.04.04.090.052_msm8974_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                                     OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
                                                                                     Build Date: 07/01/15 Wed
                                                                                     Local Branch: mybranch11515920
                                                                                     Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.1_rb1
                                                                                     Local Patches: NONE
                                                                                     Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.1_RB1.04.04.04.090.052 +  NOTHING
06-24 21:37:23.465 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-24 21:37:23.525 30643-30643/com.example.text_recognization I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@43519b38 time:579991957
```

I debug it, and it stops in the class TessBaseAPI

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("lept");
        System.loadLibrary("tess"); 
        nativeClassInit();
    }
```

I don't know whether the environment configuration is wrong or my code is wrong.
And the following is the build.grade file:

```
com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zhouying.text_recognization"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/tess-two.tesseract3.01-leptonica1.68-LibJPEG6b.jar')
}
```

if I change the support library as follows:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
```

There will be a red line indicates that "The support library shouldn't use a different version than the compileSdkVersion".
Then I change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 22, I can see errors.

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And I can see a red line under "compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'".I continue to change it to "compile 'com.android.support:design:22.0.1'.
It shows

```
Failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1
Failed to resolve com.android.support:design:22.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening due to a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91424) in some versions of the Android support library.

Try updating your support library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried your solution, but I still met some version incompatibility problems. I have used Android for a short time, could you please tell me how to update the support library in detail?

Comment: I have added some details in my question. I'm quite confused with the problem. I'm looking forward to your reply.